# How to apply an RNN to forecast non-stationary time series?

Tags: time-series, lstm, rnn, forecasting

Is it possible to predict a time series which is non-stationary, in the sense that, the dependent variable Y have an increasing trend? Therefore, the highest value of $Y$ in the training set may be lower than $Y$'s in the test set. Af far as I know, RNNs output some scaled-down version of the dependent variable. Is it possible to scale it back, when the range of values is also changing?

(One of) the independent variables (after moving avg smoothing):

[image: T]

The dependent variable (after moving avg smoothing):
[image: ?]